# Difficulty Implementing DQN for Gym's Taxi-v3 Problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, rllib

I've been working on solving the [Gym Taxi-v3 problem](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/toy_text/taxi/) using reinforcement learning algorithms. Initially, I applied tabular Q-learning and after 10,000 training iterations, the algorithm achieved a mean reward of 8.x with 100% success rate, which was satisfactory.

However, when I tried to solve the problem using a DQN (Deep Q-learning Network), the results were not as good. After approximately 100 training iterations, the evaluation episode_reward_mean seems to converge at around -210 and the episode_len_mean at around 200.

According to what I have learned from ChatGPT, DQN should work for the Taxi-v3 problem. I'm unsure why my model isn't performing well.

I would appreciate if someone could provide insight into what could be going wrong and how to use DQN to solve the Taxi-v3 problem effectively. I'm particularly interested in DQN as I believe it to be more suitable for complex practical problems than tabular Q-learning.

Evaluation result screenshot
[image]

My DQN training and evaluation code

```
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPOConfig
from ray.rllib.algorithms.dqn.dqn import DQN, DQNConfig
from ray.rllib.algorithms.a2c import A2CConfig
import ray
import csv
import datetime
import os

ray.init(local_mode=True)
# ray.init(address='auto')  # connect to Ray cluster
# config = DQNConfig()

num_rollout_workers = 62
max_train_iter_times = 20000

config = DQNConfig()
config = config.environment("Taxi-v3")
config = config.rollouts(num_rollout_workers=num_rollout_workers)
config = config.framework("torch")

# Update exploration_config
exploration_config={
    "type": "EpsilonGreedy",
    "initial_epsilon": 1.0,
    "final_epsilon": 0.02,
    "epsilon_timesteps": max_train_iter_times
}
config = config.exploration(exploration_config=exploration_config)
config.evaluation_config = {
     "evaluation_interval": 10,
    "evaluation_num_episodes": 10,
}
# Update replay_buffer_config
replay_buffer_config = {
    "_enable_replay_buffer_api": True,
    "type": "MultiAgentPrioritizedReplayBuffer",
    "capacity": 1000,
    "prioritized_replay_alpha": 0.5,
    "prioritized_replay_beta": 0.5,
    "prioritized_replay_eps": 3e-6,
}
config = config.training(
    model={"fcnet_hiddens": [50, 50, 50]},
    lr=0.001,
    gamma=0.99,
    replay_buffer_config=replay_buffer_config,
    target_network_update_freq=500,
    double_q=True,
    dueling=True,
    num_atoms=1,
    noisy=False,
    n_step=3,
)

algo = DQN(config=config)
# algo = config.build()  # 2. build the algorithm,
no_improvement_counter = 0
prev_reward = None

# Get the current date
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')

# Open the csv file in write mode
with open(f'train_{current_date}.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(["Iteration", "Reward_Mean", "Episode_Length_Mean"])

    for i in range(max_train_iter_times):
        print(f'#{i}: {algo.train()}\n')  # 3. train it,
        # Save the model every 5 iterations
        if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
            checkpoint = algo.save()
            print("Model checkpoint saved at", checkpoint)

            eval_result = algo.evaluate()
            print(f'to evaluate model: {eval_result}')  # 4. and evaluate it.

            cur_reward = eval_result['evaluation']['sampler_results']['episode_reward_mean']
            cur_episode_len_mean = eval_result['evaluation']['sampler_results']['episode_len_mean']

            # Write the iteration, reward and episode length to csv
            writer.writerow([i + 1, cur_reward, cur_episode_len_mean])
            # Force the file to be written to disk immediately
            file.flush()
            os.fsync(file.fileno())

            if prev_reward is not None and cur_reward <= prev_reward:
                no_improvement_counter += 1
            else:
                no_improvement_counter = 0
            print(f'evaluated episode_reward_mean: {cur_reward}, no improvement counter: {no_improvement_counter}\n')
            if no_improvement_counter >= 20:
                print(f"Training stopped as the episode_reward_mean did not improve for 20 consecutive evaluations. totalIterNum: {i + 1}")
                break

            prev_reward = cur_reward
```

I've tried revise DQN replay_buffer_config capacity to 10000, n_step to 20, not works. The results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any improvement during training?

Assuming you do, my first gut feeling looking at your config file is that you are applying exploration at testing time. You have to make sure that the `explore` flag in the config is set to `False`, i.e. `DQNConfig.evaluation(evaluation_config={"explore": False})`

Comment: I changed to tabular Q-learning algorithm, it perfectly solved the problem. Maybe DQN is too complex for Taxi-v3 problem?

Comment: Do you found any solution?